# JQuery to compare From Date and To Date

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 textbox which has From date and To date and a ASP Submit button as below

```
<div id="validation"></div>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="FromDateTxtBox" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="ToDateTextBox" />
From Date:<asp:TextBox ID="FromDateTxtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
To Date:<asp:TextBox ID="ToDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
```

Now using jQuery I had to compare 2 dates:

```
$("#<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>").click(function () {
  var Fromdate = Date.parse($("#<%=FromDateTxtBox.ClientID %>").val());
  var Todate =  Date.parse($("#<%=ToDateTextBox.ClientID %>").val());

  if (Fromdate <= Todate) {
    $("#validation").text("is less than");
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#validation").text("greater than");
    return false;
  }
});
```

However every time it is repeating greater than. What is wrong here? My goal is if the From Date is greater than To Date it should give error message.

Comment: The issue is due to the format of your dates. The `Date()` object constructor only accepts date strings in `MM/DD/YYYY` or `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Thanks.How can we format it to compare 2 dates..

Comment: date.parse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: I have edited my code but still not working.

Comment: Just calling "Date.parse" won't improve things, if your dates aren't in the accepted format - if you read that doc it gives you a link to the accepted formats. However, here's an alternative: you can use moment.js (http://momentjs.com) - it will make this a lot easier for you - it will parse the dd/MM/yyyy format, and has built-in comparison methods like "isAfter",  "isBefore" etc.

Comment: Thanks,it is useful,is it possible using jquery without third party plugin to compare 2 dates?

Comment: it's possible, but not using dd/mm/yyyy format. You'd need to manually check it was a valid date, then manually turn it into yyyy-mm-dd format before you can make the comparison. Why re-invent the wheel? Use a library like momentJS which is proven to work. You're already using jQuery, which is a third-party plugin. It's no harm to use another one, especially when it will save time and be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks  it is useful

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var date =$("#<%=FromDateTxtBox.ClientID %>").val();
        var dates = $("#<%=ToDateTextBox.ClientID %>").val();

        var d = new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
        var dd = d.getDate();
        var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var yy = d.getFullYear();
        var newdate = yy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd;

        var ds = new Date(dates.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
        var dds = ds.getDate();
        var mms = ds.getMonth() + 1;
        var yys = ds.getFullYear();
        var newdates = yys + "/" + mms + "/" + dds;



        if (newdate <= newdates) {
            $("#validation").text("is less than");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#validation").text("greater than");
            return false;

        }

    });
```

Converted to correct format and compared.This worked for me.